# Margin-left for button vs Margin-left for text beside floated left image

Tags: css

I have an image (80*80 px) which is floated left. To the right I want some text, and a button.

The text has margin-left of 90px, and sits nicely 10px to the right of the picture. ie. the margin ignores the floated image.

I also have a button which I want to align with the text. However, when I set the margin-left for the button to 90px, it shifts the button 90px to the right of the pictures edge - ie. it doesn't seem to ignore the floated text like it does for the image.

Any ideas why this is so? I've created a simple plnkr to show what it looks like: http://plnkr.co/edit/YLgBSIYF750xgPlzrSuB

The HTML looks like this:

```
<svg class="picture" height="80px" width="80px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
  <path ...... />
</svg>

<div class="title">Some Text</div>

<button class="button">A Button</button>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
.picture {
  float: left;
}

.title {
  margin-left: 90px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.button {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You button is not a block element. Which means it gets interpreted as text that's being flowed to the left of the image.

Change the button to be `display: block` and it behaves the same way as the text.

Alternatively, make your text be wrapped in an element that's not a block element (or change the div to display: inline) and don't set a margin on it.